# My broadband switches off when waterpump switches on

Tags: broadband

I need some advice.
My broadband drops out when a sub waterpump under floor switches on(timed)is it the frequency of the pump that could be affecting it?,is there a ferrite I can use to put around the telephone line going into the router,or is there something else that I can do so I can receive a continuous connection without interference? BTW I already have a box filter connected to incoming phone line.

Comment: Sounds more like an electrical wiring problem. Perhaps both are in the basement and share the same circuit breaker? If so, could the pump be drawing more amps than the circuit supplies? Could there be a ground fault problem? Moving the broadband to a different power supply - temporarily with an extension cord might help isolate things.

Comment: My wifi drops when the microwave turns on or the house phone is being used, though with the microwave it'd be more likely that the drop is caused by interference.

Comment: When you say 'switches off' do you mean that it literally powers off, or just that you lose wifi reception? (I'm assuming it's a wi-fi router that you're using wirelessly.) Only in the latter case would I suspect anything related to radio interference, maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely an electrical problem.  You mitigate this using an automatic voltage regulator such as [this one](http://www.apc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=LE600) or a UPS with a built-in automatic voltage regulator such as [this one](http://www.apc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=BR700G).